# Show Image for a field on mouse over

Tags: jquery

I want to show an image depending on the value of a field on mouseover.
I have searched it in here, and tried some thing like below. But the problem is that i can't use #image as there is no placeholder like that.

```
 $("#s_1_1_60_0_icon").mouseover(function () {
    $(*'#image'*).show(); //displays image on mouse in
 }
 $("#s_1_1_60_0_icon").mouseleave(function(){
    $(*'#image'*).hide(); //hides image on mouse out
});
});
```

I want to show an image like a tooltip. Please suggest a direction to achieve this.

Thanks

Comment: could you be a little more specific an what you want to accomplish and show us what your DOM looks like.

Comment: @John Thanks John for responding. There is a form applet, in which One of the control is having values in dropdown. My target is to show the image based on the value which user selects for the particular column on mouse over.

Comment: can you make a fiddle or plnker?  For starters, look at the documentation for jquery. Jquery's selectors (placeholders as you've called them) are pretty much the same as css. '#' means you're looking for an element with that Id.  So if you wanted to apply something to every image you'd say $('img').  you can also do string concatenation inside the selector so if you have an image that maps to another element you can say $('#img_'+$(this).attr('id')) if the id of the corresponding image is "img_s_1_1_60_0_icon" but I could give you a better answer if I knew what the rest of your page looked lik

Comment: @Snowburnt I wanted to in Siebel application, it has a bit complex code. Which i can't put here. For simple example, i wanted to put image everytime user mouse over to the ul in below : http://jsfiddle.net/222GA/

Comment: regardless, you're going to have to be more specific. what element EXACTLY are you trying to show?  all images? The image HAS to be present in the dom for you to show it like that, you can't just assume JQuery can magically find it for you.

Comment: @Snowburnt You are right that there is no magic involved but the logic. Its a bit complex code so i dont want to go into the details. The jsfiddle link which i have provided, can you simple tell me how to get an image(like the tooltip text) when user get the control over, say, value 'Credit Card'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a simple one based on your fiddle.  http://jsfiddle.net/RnnrA/

Like with most things in web design there's millions of ways to do something.  If you can give us more details (where is the image, for example) I could give you a better way of doing it.

```
$("li a").mouseover(function(){
    $("#img_"+$(this).attr("id")).show();
});
$("li a").mouseout(function(){
    $("#img_"+$(this).attr("id")).hide();
});
```

This one's a little more complex: http://jsfiddle.net/e7UVb/

I made a div that holds the image and everytime you mouse over it creates an image element and populates it with an image then appends it to the div.  on mouseout it destroys the image element.  This will require more client calls because everytime you mouse over it needs to go get the image.  In my example I only used one image, you'll have to use some better logic to figure out which image to display for this one.

```
$("li a").mouseover(function(){
    $("#imagePlaceholder").append($("<img></img>").prop("src","http://www.psdgraphics.com/file/psd-credit-card.jpg").prop("height","50"));
});
$("li a").mouseout(function(){
    $("#imagePlaceholder").empty();
});
```

Finally, a much simpler version: http://jsfiddle.net/Zt2pu/1/

```
$("li a").mouseover(function(){
    $("#imagePlaceholder").prop("src","http://www.psdgraphics.com/file/psd-credit-card.jpg").prop("height","50");
});
$("li a").mouseout(function(){
    $("#imagePlaceholder").prop("src","");
});
```

Here I just made an empty image tag, and on mouseover I changed the src attribute.  On mouse out I emptied the src attribute. Just like the previous one, you'll have a client call to download the image on every mouse over.

Bottom line, the top one is the simplest and easiest. The client will load all of the images once and only once so there will only be the initial call to download all the images.

again, give us a better idea of what you're actually doing and we can give you a better answer on how to accomplish that.  In the meantime, have fun with this.

Comment: This detailed solution and different ways of doing is much appreciated. Thanks for all your time. I will go thru the solution you have provided and try to apply it in my case.